# 'My apps' keeps listing uninstalled ones

Tags: google-play-store

The list of 'My apps' in the Google Play Store in my Windows browser includes apps that I no longer have installed.

Is there a way to have this list correctly display my currently installed apps?

Alternatively, can I manually remove apps from this list?

I notice that this list does not contain *all* the apps that I ever tried. There are some not in this list, that if I look them up, Google still says 'Installed.'

Answer (score 1):

The list shows all apps that you have ever used.

There is a tab "Installed" and "All" which separates the installed apps and the one you have installed + used ever.

To remove some app from the list, you'll have to look into the "All" tab and a little "x" mark on the top right corner, which will remove the app from the list.

Also, please not that you can only remove an app that's no longer installed on your phone / tablet.

Comment: I am very sorry, my question was incomplete. You answer is correct for the Google Play app on my phone, but I actually meant in the web interface. I will upvote your answer but not mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @JanDoggen As far as I understand there is not any applicable method to so from the web interface. But any changes that you make in your phone will be reflected on the play store web interface as well.